# How vertically center div in bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I wand to create square boxes with a text center in it. Below is what I wish :
[image]

I'm using Django and Bootstrap. To do my square, I have followed the instructions here : http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Then, here it is my HTML code :

```
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column">
        <div class='row flex-fill'>
          <div class='colonne_salle col-sm-2'>
            <div class='row'>
                {% for s in salle %}
                <div class='col-sm-6 square'>
                  <div class="bloc-salle" id="{{ s.name }}">
                      <h3 class='nom-salle'>{{ s.name }}</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
```

And my css :

```
.bloc-salle{
  /* margin : 15px 0 15px 0; */
  position:  absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.square:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
```

For the moment, I'm getting this result : 
[image]

Thanks a lot if you can help me !

EDIT : 
In the answer I find about square grid, none of them describe how to center vertically the content inside of each square.

Answer (score 1):

You can use align-center with .bloc-salle

Comment: Thans a lot for you advice, but it doesn't work :(